# C# Is it possible to make a groupBox title as a radio button?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to make a groupBox title as a radio button ?
If it's possible, I want to make the whole groupBox dependant of the radioButton.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a `RadioButton` to your `Form`. Make sure it's **no** control of the `GroupBox`.

Add to the constructor of your `Form`:

```
radioButton.Location = new Point(groupBox.Location.X + 13, groupBox.Location.Y - 1);
```

Everything else is possible through `Events`.

Comment: The event code would be super easy too `radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { groubBox.Enabled = radioButton.Checked; }`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain For this kind of issue I would use a simple `CheckBox`.

Comment: If you have multiple GroupBoxes and you only want one of them to be active you would need to use a RadioButton, I assumed that is the case with the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this directly, no. You might be able to make a custom control that combined the two things. Alternatively you might just need to have the `GroupBox` not have a title and put the `RadioButton` over it. A little kludgy, of course, but it doesn't look bad.